# md5 salt hash can't find equal entry in DB

Tags: php, mysql

For now I am trying to check if in MysSql database is same password. But I am failing and I don't get it why.

```
$username = 'blablabla';
$password = 'blablabla.';
$salt = 'blablabla';
$new = md5($password.md5($salt));
echo($new);
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mdl_user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$new'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
```

In config file which defines salt word I used the same as above.

EDITED:
Is it possible to get hash algorythm from this code?

```
function validate_internal_user_password($user, $password) {
global $CFG; 
if (!isset($CFG->passwordsaltmain)) { 
$CFG->passwordsaltmain = ''; 
} 
$validated = false; 
if ($user->password === 'not cached') { 
// internal password is not used at all, it can not validate 
} else if ($user->password === md5($password.$CFG->passwordsaltmain) 
    or $user->password === md5($password) 
    or $user->password === md5(addslashes($password).$CFG->passwordsaltmain) 
    or $user->password === md5(addslashes($password))) { 
// note: we are intentionally using the addslashes() here because we 
//       need to accept old password hashes of passwords with magic quotes 
$validated = true; 
} else { 
for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) { //20 alternative salts should be enough, right? 
    $alt = 'passwordsaltalt'.$i; 
    if (!empty($CFG->$alt)) { 
        if ($user->password === md5($password.$CFG->$alt) or $user->password === md5(addslashes($password).$CFG->$alt)) { 
            $validated = true; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
} 
} 
if ($validated) { 
// force update of password hash using latest main password salt and encoding if needed 
update_internal_user_password($user, $password); 
} 
return $validated;
```

**EDITED**
I tried this code:

```
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'Vidsodis25.'+'Karolina';
$new = md5($password);
echo($new);
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mdl_user WHERE password = '$new'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
```

Database uses same salt word Karolina. But still can't find correct one.

Comment: The hashing algorithm the same as when you put the existing password in?

Comment: Are you sure that the entry actually exists in the database? Can you post the contents of the row as seen in your database?

Comment: I don't know which algorythm is used because it hashes automatically. Is there few ways to do this?

Comment: Of course. For example, `$new = md5($password.md5($salt));` could be like `$new = md5(md5($salt).$password);`. There even could be any intermediate character between them, such as `:` or `.`.

Comment: Uhm, it's not per-user salt? :( And if it is (*as it should be*), is that being saved/restored correctly? Generally, one does *not* try to find a user by a hash, but rather, finds by username, and then verifies by hash (utilizing found salt).

Comment: edited above. Maybe this would be helpfull?

Comment: There are 4 conditionals being tested to determine if the password matches, none of which are md5(salt) like you are in your example. Try changing `$new = md5($password.md5($salt));` to `$new = md5($password.$salt);`

Comment: tried that already, not working

Comment: @pst could you explain it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said in the comments,  either:

1. The password/name/salt is incorrect (bad input)
2. The hash is incorrect (generated differently or with different salt)
3. The hash is incorrect for the given user (e.g. it doesn't match, no record, etc)

Now, the way the hashing is done looks ... wrong. The idea of a salt is to *stop* rainbow table attacks, which makes the attacker have to rely on brute force to "crack" a given password.

Anyway, for *each* new password hash saved, generate a new *random* salt value (like, say, 128 bits or more). This one-of-a-kind *nonce* is then used to salt the password *before* it is hashed. The hash **and** the salt are then saved together (they are often combined into a value, but it's okay if they are in separate columns).

So, to make sure the password is valid:

1. Find the row representing the user *first* and extract the hash **and** salt
2. Generate the hash from the password using the salt; if hash/salt was saved as a combined value separate it first as needed
3. Verify the generated hash and the stored hash

That is, the query should likely *not* search for `username = '$username' AND password = '$new'"` (where `password` should really be called `hash` or similar) because the salt *needs to be available* to generate the correct hash again. In the above code snippets it's doing some monkey business with 20-some different preset salts. This is not the correct way to do it, and requires that each one of the *potential* salts is used in the hash generation so the "right hash" can be found. (Translated into the `select` in the post this would require up to 20 different executions and/or use of `in` or something similar.)

In addition, do not use MD5 for password hashes. It is *too easy to brute force*. Do not use SHAx either; it is still too fast as it was not designed for this purpose either. Use something like `bcrypt` or `scrypt`. If you do want a "server salt" (which is a *good additional layer*) then use an HMAC. This does not replace the normal salt. Oh, and *please don't use SQL-injection prone code*!

I would use an existing well-vetted library :)

Happy coding.